# Print several values in the same line with commas

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python (as well as stackoverflow) and I was wondering how I could print several values with commas in between them.

I'm very well aware of the `end` keyword the `print` function takes, but the problem is that it appends the string after every value, including the last one, which is precisely what I don't want.

So, instead of maybe 1,2,3,4, ; what I want is 1,2,3,4.

Update:
I'm sorry I wasn't so clear as I didn't post my code. Here it is:

```
N = int(input())
p = []
for i in range(N):
    P = str(input())
    p.append(P)
for i in range(N):
    print(p[N-1-i],end=', ')
```

N sets the number of following inputs and I want the program to print every entry on the same line but backwards, with each of them separated by comma and space. I think sep doesn't quite work here.

Comment: Hi. you should post your code in order to let us better understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

`print` also takes a `sep` argument which specifies the separator between the other arguments.

```
>>> print(1, 2, 3, 4, sep=',')
1,2,3,4
```

If you have an iterable of things to print, you can unpack it with the `*args` syntax.

```
>>> stuff_to_print = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(*stuff_to_print, sep=',')
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4']  
s = ",".join(list1) 
print(s)
```